# Windows 10 + Ruby 2.5.1 и кодировка cp1251 или UTF-8

Tags: кодировка, ruby, windows-10, utf-8, кириллица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хочу разобратся именно с Windows 10 под Ruby 2.5.x
Пробовал две кодировки 1251 и 65001 (UTF-8)
В 1251 не выводит кириллицу именно просто не отображает и не видит так как значение символов  0 указанно после того как я ввел имя Андрей.
А в utf-8 не хочет работать.
Выдает различные ошибки то что то с битами не то, то еще что то (ошибки выводит разные, в зависимости как и что настраиваю)
Правил кодировки в самой консоли через chcp вы только спасете себя если будете именно в этой консоли выводить обычные строки. А вот если запустите файл руби с кодом, где введете в переменную Русское слово, будет просто пусто в выводе строки.
Еще редактировал в реестре кодировку в папке "CodePages" или "CodePage" пишу с телефона ноут не рядом. Поэтому могу чуть в названии ошибиться. 
Уже и сам test.rb файл сохранял в разной кодировки.
И в файле добавлял кодировку # encoding: cp1251 и так же пробовал UTF-8.

Помогите с настройкой. Что я делаю не так ??
У кого в Windows 10 нормально работает Ruby с кириллицей (с выводом руского текста) от версии 2.4.4 и выше ??
Уже месяца два мучаюсь. 
Хочу именно под Windows 10. За ubuntu я знаю что там все работает нормально.

Comment: А если вводить просто на русском то даже не считает символы. Просто пишет "0" Букв!

# coding: utf-8
print "Введите ваше имя: "
name = gets.strip.capitalize
puts "Доброе время, \t #{name} \nВ вашем Имени \t #{name}, #{name.size} букв" 

PS D:\Projects\Ruby\Lesson> ruby test.rb
Введите ваше имя: Андрей!!
Доброе время,          !!
В вашем Имени          !!, 8 букв

Comment: А попробуйте вывести `name.bytes`.

Comment: Я не могу задавать такую переменную. Ошибку выдает что не правильная команда.

Comment: Зачем задавать? Я ж вывести предложил. И если выводит ошибку, прикладывайте именно её, а не собственную интерпретацию.

Comment: По подробней... как я вам ее выведу ? Скажите действия какие нужно сделать.

Comment: Точно так же, как вы выводите `name`, с помощью `puts` или аналогов.

Comment: не выйдет так как нет такой переменной и такого значения (обьекта) ".bytes"

`Введите ваше имя: Traceback (most recent call last):
5.1.1.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `name' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: Как это нет? В `name` же у вас строка, нет?

Comment: name - это переменная

Comment: Есть puts и print -  это строки.

ВСЕ! Я вас понял! Через переменную в CMD Windows:

`C:\Users\andre>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\Users\andre>irb
irb(main):001:0> str = gets.bytes
Андрей
=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
irb(main):002:0>`

А это в Visual Studio Code: 

`PS D:\Projects\Ruby\Lesson\5\5.1> ruby 5.1.1.rb
Введите ваше имя: Андрей
Доброе время суток, [128, 173, 164, 224, 165, 169, 10]
PS D:\Projects\Ruby\Lesson\5\5.1>`

Comment: В первом случае Ruby явно не понял, что ему ввели осмысленные символы.

Comment: Это без .bytes выводит в cmd.exe:

`irb(main):003:0> x = gets
Андрей
=> "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\n"`

Comment: Ну, собственно, видно: вместо кириллических символов в стандартный ввод попали нули. Это запросто может быть прикол виндовой консоли. Там, помнится, CP866. Возможно, если переключить кодировку стандартного ввода, взлетит. А возможно, стоит попробовать другие консольки: mintty, cmder...